# Redirect URLs ending with a dot

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect URLs ending with a dot but it doesn't work...

I have tested with this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tum_and_valhalla.$ /tum_and_valhalla
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tum_and_valhalla\.$ /tum_and_valhalla
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tum_and_valhalla(.*)$ /tum_and_valhalla
```

but none of them are working.
How should it be done?

I would also be very grateful to get input on how to deal with URLs including an &
Example:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/ol&t$ /olt
```

Thanks!

Comment: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/tum_and_valhalla\.$ /tum_and_valhalla` actually works.

Comment: I tried again by moving it the line to the begnning of the htaccess doc and then it works...! Must be something disturbing the rule if it is to late.